# How to use both sortable and froalaEditor

Tags: editor, jquery-ui-sortable

How can I use sortable and inline froalaEditor on a html?

The ui sortable https://jqueryui.com/sortable/
The editor: https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/examples/inline

My JS code:

```
$('.row').sortable();
$('div.container').froalaEditor({
    toolbarInline: true,
    toolbarButtons: ['fullscreen', 'bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strikeThrough', 'subscript', 'superscript', '|', 'fontFamily', 'fontSize', 'color', 'inlineStyle', 'paragraphStyle', '|', 'paragraphFormat', 'align', 'formatOL', 'formatUL', 'outdent', 'indent', 'quote', '-', 'insertLink', 'insertImage', 'insertVideo', 'embedly', 'insertFile', 'insertTable', '|', 'emoticons', 'specialCharacters', 'insertHR', 'selectAll', 'clearFormatting', '|', 'print', 'spellChecker', 'help', 'html', '|', 'undo', 'redo'],
    toolbarButtonsXS: null,
    toolbarButtonsSM: null,
    toolbarButtonsMD: null
  });
```

My html:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <img class="" src="./sections/headers/header-logo-slogan-cards/images/logo2-light-big.png" srcset="./sections/headers/header-logo-slogan-cards/images/logo2-light-big@2x.png 2x" class="mb-50" alt="Gumapp">
            <h1 class="mb-40">Innovative solutions and design</h1>
            <div class="spr-option-copy-del aos-init aos-animate" data-aos="stretch-left" data-aos-easing="linear" data-aos-duration="800" data-aos-delay="400" style="height:2px;background-color:#ffffff;box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ffffff;"></div>
            <h3 class="mb-75 mt-40">So, what is the secret of successful template design?<br> First of all, it is its friendliness.</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="card light spr-option-item-img">
                <img src="./sections/headers/header-logo-slogan-cards/images/card-bg-1.jpg" class="card-img spr-option-img-nosettings" alt="">
                <div class="card-img-overlay-bottom">
                    <h3>Technology</h3>
                    <p class="mb-20">Emotions that causes your project in visitor are no less important ticket to success</p>
                    <a class="btn btn-default btn-sm" href="#"><span class="spr-option-textedit-link">Read more</span></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I try this way with above JS, sortable not working.

Thank so much

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested the code, but have an educated guess. You init the editor on the container class, in which the row class exists. Inspect the container element and probably the row class is gone and replaced by the editor. You should probably init sortable on another div surrounding the container, or init the froala editor on a different one.

Answer (score 0):

When using a sortable element, it requires to disable the selection on that element, therefore it is no longer editable. The best approach would be to use a dragging handler so that both sortable and the editor would work together.